# Coloring data points for different ranges

Tags: plotting, color, data

```
data={{1,79},{2,82},{3,77},{4,81},{5,83},{6,63},{7,80},{8,81},{9,83},{10,81},{11,80},{12,76},{13,78},{14,74},
    {15,74},{16,76},{17,76},{18,74},{19,72},{20,79},{21,80},{22,74},{23,76},{24,74},{25,63},{26,72},{27,69},{28,83},{29,86},{30,67},{31,84},{32,79},{33,74},
{34,80},{35,77},{36,81},{37,79},{38,78},{39,78},{40,77},{41,75},{42,80},{43,83},{44,78},{45,80},{46,60},
    {47,76},{48,73},{49,78},{50,83},{51,84},{52,79},{53,84},{54,78},{55,74},{56,78},{57,81},{58,85},{59,88},{60,80},{61,85},{62,79},{63,82},{64,83},
{65,84},{66,86},{67,80},{68,62},{69,79},{70,68},{71,80},{72,77},{73,78},{74,72},{75,0},{76,75},{77,73},{78,72},{79,79},{80,73},{81,65},{82,77},{83,79},
{84,72},{85,73},{86,75},{87,70},{88,83},{89,81},{90,82},{91,83},
{92,64},{93,74},{94,60},{95,80},{96,77},{97,76},{98,70},{99,72},{100,79},{101,75},{102,77},{103,73},{104,80},{105,76},{106,75},{107,79},{108,75},{109,66},{110,67}}
```

In the above table, the 1st column is the serial number and the second column is for marks. When I plot the above table using `ListPlot`, all points render in blue. However, I want a graph, in which marks from **60 to 69** use a single color, **70-79** use a different color and **80-89** use yet another color**.

How to do this?

Currently, I am using the following code:

```
ListPlot[data[[All, {1, 2}]], PlotStyle -> styles1,  PlotRange -> {-1, 100}]
```

where `styles1` is defined as follows:

```
styles1 = Table[ColorData["BrightBands"], 110]; 
styles1[[4 ;; 15]] = Directive[Red, PointSize[0.02]]; 
styles1[[1 ;; 3]] = Directive[PointSize[0.01]]; 
styles1[[16 ;; 110]] = Directive[PointSize[0.01]];
```

This was working in conjunction with another problem; however, for some reason, it is not working presently.
Besides this is not the right way to do it. Please help me out or point me in the right direction.

Comment: One of your points is `{75,0}`. It seems like an outlier. But you can provide an update if required..

Comment: yes, that's correct. at 75 serial number the value is 0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way could be:

```
dnew = GatherBy[data, Quotient[Last@#, 10] &];
ListPlot[dnew]
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`BinLists`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BinLists.html) to bin data using your desired thresholds:

```
binData = Apply[Join]@ReplaceAll[{} -> Nothing]@BinLists[#, {#2}, {#3}] &;
```

***Examples:***

Bin input data based on y-coordinates using bin limits `{0, 60, 70, 80, 90}`:

```
 ListPlot[binData[data, MinMax[data[[All, 1]]], {0, 60, 70, 80, 90}],
 GridLines -> {None, {0, 60, 70, 80, 90}}]
```

[image]

Bin input data based on x-ccordinates using bin limits `{0, 60, 70, 80, 90}`:

```
ListPlot[binData[data, {0, 60, 70, 80, 90}, MinMax[data[[All, 2]]]],
 GridLines -> {{0, 60, 70, 80, 90}, None}]
```

[image]

Use bin limits `{0, 50, 80, 110}` and `{0, 60, 70, 80, 90}` for x and y coordinates, respectively:

```
ListPlot[binData[data, {0, 50, 80, 110}, {0, 60, 70, 80, 90}],
 GridLines -> {{0, 50, 80, 110}, {0, 60, 70, 80, 90}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the following script by which you can customize the color, marker and size of marker for each set of data as well.

```
datap = Join[{Select[data, 60 < #[[2]] < 69 &], 
        Select[data, 70 < #[[2]] < 79 &], 
        Select[data, 80 < #[[2]] < 89 &]}];
ListPlot[datap, PlotStyle -> Thread[{Red, Green, Blue}], 
    PlotMarkers -> {"\[FilledSquare]", "\[FilledUpTriangle]", 
    "\[FilledCircle]"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can define your coloring function:

```
theStyleFunction[ind_] := 
 Piecewise[{{Blue, 60 <= ind <= 69}, {Red, 70 <= ind <= 79}, {Green, 
    80 <= ind <= 89}}, Black]



ListPlot[data[[All, {1, 2}]], 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, theStyleFunction[x]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotRange -> {-1, 100}, 
 PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.02]]
```

Comment: It's not working as desired because the above code segments the data along x-axis. where as I needed along y-axis

Comment: Simply replace theStyleFunction[x] by theStyleFunction[y] in ListPlot.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some other variants to show use of [`GroupBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html), [`SortBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SortBy.html), [`SplitBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SplitBy.html).

I have voted for the other answers that deal with  partitioning data, Style can modified as desired.

```
gb = GroupBy[data, Floor[#[[2]]/10] &];
ListPlot[Values[gb], GridLines -> {None, 10 Keys[gb]}]
```

yields:
[image]

```
SplitBy[SortBy[data, Last], Floor[#[[2]]/10] &] // ListPlot
```

yields:

[image]